What was the first official speedrun?
These days, speedruns are a fact of life when it comes to video games. Someone, somewhere, has tried to be the fastest person to ever beat that game (or more recently, beat a specific challenge in a game).
What was the first official speedrun (what time was it)? Who did it? What game was it in?

I do not know for sure but would think it would be like most games that you beat, collected everything, and nothing else to do but you still love the game so you give yourself a challenge to beat it as fast as you can.  Then you share it, and others try to beat yours and so on.

This seems rather opinion-based and off-topic; people everywhere, anywhere, at all times have wanted to be the fastest and/or best at things. What makes this different? Or do you want to know who  was the first person to (publicly, officially) perform a speedrun?

@Joachim Yeah I can see what you mean. Sure, first official speedrun works.

What do you mean by 'official'? What qualifies a speedrun as official? Imo, this point needs to be clarified.

@Time4Tea Off the top of my head, I’d say any speedrun made public some way or another.

And not cheated or TASed.

One of the first examples should be Activision's Dragster for Atari 2600 (1980):

The game manual challenged the players to achieve a time lower than 6 seconds. Sending a proof of your record to Activision let you enter the World Class Dragster club.
EDIT:
According to Polygon:

In 1982, Todd Rogers submitted to Activision’s official fan newsletter a time of 5.51 seconds, which the company recognized in print, awarding Rogers a patch. Twin Galaxies (the video game record keeper) later added Rogers to its own leaderboards in 2001, and Guinness World Records awarded the player with the honor of holding the world’s longest-standing gaming record in April 2017.


This answer reminded me of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326012/what-tools-were-used-to-analyze-challenge-the-records-for-dragster  To be honest though, I don't quite know if you would consider this a speedrun... it was literally just the game but who am I to say ;)

@TimmyJim yeah I have mixed feelings too, but OP wrote "Someone, somewhere, has tried to be the fastest person to ever beat that game" and this fits to me.

@pinckerman That doesn't really answer the question. I asked what the speedrun time was and who did it, and all you answered with was the game.

Those details are actually in the linked q&a from Timmy Jim; Todd Rogers, 5.51 seconds.

@Daemons 5.51s it's the offcial record, but it's probably obtained cheating because with TAS we know that "down to the individual frame level (shifting and accelerating at the exact best possible moment), results in a time of 5.57s"

Yes, please note that Todd Rogers is a known cheat and liar; the time of 5.51 seconds in Dragster is impossible to achieve, and most of Rogers' records were entered into the speedrun site by friends or himself with no proof given.

Some extra information about the record and why it was a scam: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrH7aPmO61w

If this was a cheated record(?), it can’t really be called “official”.

Really, an 'official' speedrun needs to be recorded. Otherwise, anyone can say they completed a certain challenge in X amount of time.
